# iptables minimum system

Tags: iptables

I would like to set up a dedicated firewall with a minimal linux. I need something that just has absolutely the minimum and no more:

- iptables
- ssh access
- basic tools

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use `alpine linux` and if you're not looking for Ubuntu specific solution ask your question at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Unless you're trying to torture yourself, look into dedicated firewall releases like "IPCop", "IPFire". Others have already done the work.